# TF60024 Error attempting to migrate VSS to TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, vssconverter

I keep getting the TF60024 error "Unable to create the intermediate database required by VSS Converter on Microsoft SQL Server .\SQLEXPRESS.  CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."  When I run the VSSConverter with "Migrate" and my xml file.

Here is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <SourceControlConverter>
        <ConverterSpecificSetting>
          <Source name="VSS">
                <VSSDatabase name="z:\CHS_SourceSafe"></VSSDatabase>
          </Source>
          <ProjectMap>
            <Project Source="$/Account Automation SQL" Destination="$/Account Automation SQL"></Project>
<!--Other projects excluded-->
         </ProjectMap>
        </ConverterSpecificSetting>
        <Settings>
                <TeamFoundationServer name="CHS-TFS" port="8080" protocol="http" collection="tfs/DefaultCollection"></TeamFoundationServer></Settings>
     </SourceControlConverter>
```

My network guy told me to mention:

I am a local admin on the Server (CHS-TFS)

I am a sys adm on both TFS 2010 64 bit and SQL Server (2008 R2 64 bit).

I'm running this from the (win 7): "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" folder.

The ANALYZE function returned 0 errors.

I've tried adding the ".root" to the end of the Source, that didn't help.

We also tried NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE full access (thinking that maybe it was using that as a default login)

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** 
I found this one blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx
that seemed to deal with the issue, I worked though it, and still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Is your "network guy" sure you are Sys Admin on the whole SQL server and not only on the TFS database? Because the error message says you don't have enough permission on SQL Server. What is confusing to me is the SQLEXPRESS in your error message, because you said you are using SQL 2008 R2. Do you run a local SQL Express instance on the machine, might be that you need permissions there.

Comment: I'll ask him when he gets in.  I asked if the SQL Express was the same thing as the SQL Server 2008 R2 yesterday, and he said it was.  It was basically the 2008 R2 SQLEXPRESS edition, that way we didn't need to waste a license on that installation.  And the TFS docs said it worked fine with the SQLEXPRESS instance...

Comment: I just checked with our network manager, and he checked I'm a sys admin on the TFS server, and he said that if I'm a sys admin on the server that SQLEXPRESS automatically takes those users as sys admins in the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this a different way.  I watched this video:

[You Tube video that explains other way of doing this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZrHYsVadao)

And downloaded this tool:

[File to download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/867f310a-db30-4228-bbad-7b9af0089282)

And it was much easier to do.